# Swift, super.init() Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIView' error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new with Swift. I inherited a project. I saw it running on a device. However, when I checkout the code and it had many errors. I was able to clear out the errors. However, I run into this one that is baffling me. The project uses xib files as well. Here is the code.

```
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

   init(items:NSArray, viewController:AnyObject){
        super.init()
        //itemsArray = items
        itemsArray = items as [AnyObject]
        //commonInit(viewController as UIViewController)
        commonInit(viewController as! UIViewController)
    }
```

I get the error under the init(items:NSArray, viewController:AnyObject) method/function. The error is pointed at the "super.init()". It states "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIView' error"

I been searching, googling, asking others and nothing has turned up.
Can I get help on fixing this error, or at least why this error happens? I would like understand so I can become a better software developer.

Edit: I would like to thank everyone for their insight and help. I found out the problem is bigger. I did the changes suggested in the super.init(frame: CGRect). I had to change an array property as well which was affecting the init function.

Comment: try to change super.init() in self.init()

Answer (score 19):

As the error message suggests you can only call the designated initializer of the superclass.

To solve this you need to call : `super.init(frame: frame)` instead of `super.init()`

Comment: what frame size needs to send in super.init(frame: frame). My view have flexible width and height.

Comment: Well, you can always send a bogus height and width and change it afterwards. Although I would recommend trying to get the right size from the start. If it has a flexible width and height, surely you must know them.

Answer (score 15):

`UIView`'s designated initializers are:

```
init(frame: CGRect)
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

You're calling `super.init()` which is an initializer inherited from its superclass `NSObject`. Use one of those initialises instead as the compiler is suggesting in order to (actually) invoke the `super` constructor which could be one of the 2 above.

If it helps, another example is if you inherits from `UIViewController` and then you create your own init you can only invoke one the two:

1. [init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init)
2. [init?(coder: NSCoder)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621403-init)

i.e:

```
init() {
  super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really give any more information than the error message.

Comment: not useful information to fix the issue